# Show the graph {$(x,f(x))| x\in \mathbb{R}$} is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (standard metric), show its graph: {$(x,f(x))| x\in\mathbb{R}$} is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (euclidean metric).

I went about this by re-writing the graph as {$(x,y)| y- f(x)= 0$} and then just stated that this is the preimage of the closed set: $\{0\}$. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost over. You have to show that the function 
$$\varphi(x,y)=y-f(x)$$
is continuous from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then the graph is the  preimage of a closed set by the continuous function $\varphi$, and hence must be closed as well.

To prove continuity, show that if $(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow (x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ then $\varphi(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow\varphi(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $g(x,y)=y-f(x)$ . Then $g$ is continuous o $ \mathbb R^2$ and

$g^{-1}(\{0\})=\{(x,f(x): x \in \mathbb R\}$